# PHP Convert emojis from UTF-8 to UTF-8 Bytes (UTF-16)

Tags: php, utf-8, emoji, utf-16

So I need this: \ud83d\ude01  turned into this: \xF0\x9F\x98\x81
I have been digging around and for the life of me I can not figure out how that would be done.
Can someone please help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use json_encode function

Comment: That only gives me: \\ud83d\\ude01

Comment: Where does "\ud83d\ude01" come from? Is that supposed to be a JSON string? If you `json_decode('"\ud83d\ude01"')`, you get your emoji. What does "\xF0\x9F\x98\x81" represent exactly? Literally a string with "backslash ex eff …", or a UTF-8 encoded string representing an emoji?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ud83d\ude01` is an [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Escape_sequences) for 16-bit Unicode characters and what you apparently want is an 8-bit character escape sequence (using hex digits).

As already pointed out, you can use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get the actual emoji from your unicode escape sequence:

```
$str = "\ud83d\ude01";
$str = json_decode('"' . $str . '"');
echo $str;    //
```

You can then make use of [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to get every byte of that emoji in an array as mentioned in the documentation:

> str_split() will split into bytes, rather than characters when dealing with a multi-byte encoded string.

In order to convert every byte to its hex representation, use [`ord()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) and [`dechex()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php):

```
$bytes = str_split($str);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($bytes); $i++) {
    $bytes[$i] = "\x" . dechex(ord($bytes[$i]));
}
$str = implode('',$bytes);
```

Note that you need to add `\x` in front of every hex digit by yourself to get the desired sequence.

Everything put together:

```
$str = "\ud83d\ude01";
$str = json_decode('"' . $str . '"');
$bytes = str_split($str);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($bytes); $i++) {
    $bytes[$i] = "\x" . dechex(ord($bytes[$i]));
}
$str = implode('',$bytes);

echo $str;    // \xf0\x9f\x98\x81
```

https://3v4l.org/A1PEn